# Incorrect vote count?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, up-votes, voting

I have looked at [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2683?tab=stats#sort-top) and his [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered/271471#271471) is for question "What is the best comment in source code you have ever encountered?"

While ordinarily I would not care, the vote counts are quite disproportionate: 408 stated on the userpage, and 4 on the question page itself. There is a tag "(2)" next to the link to answer on the userpage. Could that be related, and if so, how is it related?

Comment: Where is that duplicate? I know this has been asked before...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The user has multiple answer to the question, they have +404 for this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618/185106#185106). The `(n)` (in this case 2) means the user has multiple answers to the question. I don't know that it is documented which answer you will be taken to if you click on the link in the case of multiple answers. I *think* the most recently posted, but again, I don't know that its been documented.

Comment: A tooltip when pointing over that number would be great.

Answer (score 3):

The (2) indicates that this user has posted 2 answers for that question.  His [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered/185106#185106) accounts for the discrepancy in upvotes.